# How to access Windows files from Ubuntu - dual boot

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I'm running a duel partition with Windows Vista home premium and Ubuntu 12, but my Windows Vista crashed after installing the recent updates from Microsoft.

My laptop is an Intel dual core from Gateway. I'm going to do a factory restore of the laptop after I get my files transferred.

How would you view the files from Windows Vista in Ubuntu 12?

Comment: first try mounting the windows partition and then post the errors if any

Comment: @mchid Ignore me, I'm using Wubi. It's already mounted in host.

Comment: @mchid: see comment below answer... **:-/**  drop me a note [at]Fabby here to get your stance.

Comment: @mchid: if you're cool with it them I'm cool with it.  upvoted as well, comment removed!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby it seemed like agreeing with me more than reposting it

Answer (score 3):

As [mchid](https://askubuntu.com/users/167115/mchid) said in the comments, mount the Windows partition by clicking on it in the file manager or on the launcher.